# How to identify the polyfuse used in this RS-485 module

Tags: identification, fuses, rs485, polyfuse

This is the popular RS-485 module found in the market, how can I identify the polyfuse/heat recovery fuse in it? Also its manufacturer or electrical ratings?

[image: photo of RS-485 module]

Comment: Might be Bourns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be Bourns MF-MSMF Series, specifically MF-MSMF010 
[Mouser link](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Bourns/MF-MSMF010-2?qs=mkjPM10ZYVYU4yEEad9W7w%3D%3D)
60V DC Max
100mA Hold
300mA Trip

[image: Part Marking]

[MF-MSMF Series Datasheet](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/mfmsmf.pdf?sfvrsn=4a75e5c0_54)